# Inner Join between two different tables in T-SQL query

Tags: sql-server, ssms, inner-join

In SQL Server, suppose I have table 'A' with a column `ID` with values (1, 1, 1, 1, 1) and table 'B' has the same column `ID` with values (1, 1, 1).

What would be the resulting output of the two if there's an `INNER JOIN` between the two on the ID columns?

Please note that there are no additional columns in any of the tables.

Comment: You'll get **15 rows** - each with a `1` from table A, and another `1` from table B

Answer (score 0):

If you have a table with 5 rows, and another with 3 rows, and each of those rows have the same value to join on - you will get the result of 5 x 3 = 15 rows.

The logic is this:

- you get the first row from `tableA` - `ID = 1` - and this will be joined against all rows in `tableB`, based on the `ID` column in `tableB`, that have the same value - so in this case: all 3 rows.
- and this happens for the second, third, fourth and fifth row in `tableA` as well.

Screenshot is pointless - you'll just see 15 rows of `1 | 1` - values from both tables are both 1 ...

And any other join will work just the same ......

Not really sure what you're trying to achieve / understand there ..... this is a really "constructed" sample, and doesn't make a lot of sense to talk about much more. You should really find a more useful, more realistic example to learn about the joins and their functioning and their differences ..